# How to convert csv data into tuples with numpy genfromtxt?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I've been having trouble calling csv files in form of tuples with python.

I'm using:

```
csv_data = np.genfromtxt('csv-data.csv', dtype=int, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

While the data looks like: (sorry I don't know how to display csv format)

```
Trial1 Trial2 Trial3
50-------70----90
60-------70----80
```

(data of 3 trials by 2 people)

My `genfromtxt()` code from above would generate:

```
csv_data=[(50, 70, 90) (60, 70, 80)]
```

While I want to separate the data by person with a comma like:

```
csv_data = [(50, 70, 90), (60, 70, 80)]
```

Any help from here on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `tolist` method.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

It will convert the ndarray to a list.

```
import numpy as np
csv_data = np.genfromtxt('csv-data.csv', dtype=int, delimiter=',', names=True)
print(csv_data.tolist())
```

The result of the above code is:

```
➜ /tmp/csv $ python3 test.py
[(50, 70, 90), (60, 70, 80)]
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Wow just works perfectly as I wanted. Thank you so much!!